# Jenkins xcode plugin stringRep should be a non-empty string, but it's an empty string

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, xcode6

I'm trying to build an iOS app using jenkins Xcode plugin. Unfortunately it fails with error

```
 stringRep should be a non-empty string, but it's an empty string
```

Below I put full stack. When I run

```
/usr/bin/xcodebuild -list -workspace project.xcworkspace
```

in terminal, it gives correct output.

```
    == Available schemes
[repository] $ /usr/bin/xcodebuild -list -workspace project.xcworkspace
2015-07-18 15:33:40.533 xcodebuild[39418:3378293] [MT] DVTAssertions: ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/DVTFrameworks/DVTFrameworks-7714/DVTFoundation/MacroExpansion/DVTMacroDefinitionConditionSet.mm:153
Details:  stringRep should be a non-empty string, but it's an empty string
Object:   <DVTMacroDefinitionConditionSet>
Method:   +conditionSetFromStringRepresentation:getBaseMacroName:error:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7f909152e100>{number = 1, name = main}
Hints: None
Backtrace:
  0  0x0000000102a27c07 -[DVTAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] (in DVTFoundation)
  1  0x0000000102a2765f _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x0000000102a2794e _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  3  0x00000001029b581e +[DVTMacroDefinitionConditionSet conditionSetFromStringRepresentation:getBaseMacroName:error:] (in DVTFoundation)
  4  0x000000010475f062 -[DVTMacroDefinitionTable(XCMacroExpansionExtensions) _xc_setValue:forMacroName:errorHandler:] (in DevToolsCore)
  5  0x000000010475f6a9 __108-[DVTMacroDefinitionTable(XCMacroExpansionExtensions) xc_setMacroNamesAndValuesFromDictionary:errorHandler:]_block_invoke (in DevToolsCore)
  6  0x00007fff8fec21f5 __65-[__NSDictionaryI enumerateKeysAndObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]_block_invoke (in CoreFoundation)
  7  0x00007fff8fec2119 -[__NSDictionaryI enumerateKeysAndObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] (in CoreFoundation)
  8  0x000000010475f585 -[DVTMacroDefinitionTable(XCMacroExpansionExtensions) xc_setMacroNamesAndValuesFromDictionary:errorHandler:] (in DevToolsCore)
  9  0x0000000104762109 -[NSProcessInfo(XCMacroExpansionExtensions) xc_cachedEnvironmentAsMacroDefinitionTable] (in DevToolsCore)
 10  0x00000001045357fa -[PBXTarget createMacroExpansionScopeWithBuildParameters:] (in DevToolsCore)
 11  0x0000000104537bd2 -[PBXTarget cachedMacroExpansionScopeForBuildParameters:] (in DevToolsCore)
 12  0x000000010454c903 -[PBXTarget expandedValueForString:forBuildParameters:] (in DevToolsCore)
 13  0x00000001045c1869 -[PBXNativeTarget fullProductNameForConfigurationNamed:] (in DevToolsCore)
 14  0x0000000104545d40 -[PBXTarget fullProductName] (in DevToolsCore)
 15  0x0000000104505deb -[PBXReference setProducingTarget:] (in DevToolsCore)
 16  0x000000010454a480 -[PBXTarget awakeFromPListUnarchiver:] (in DevToolsCore)
 17  0x00000001045c2616 -[PBXNativeTarget awakeFromPListUnarchiver:] (in DevToolsCore)
 18  0x00007fff8fe6f376 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:withObject:] (in CoreFoundation)
 19  0x000000010451c864 -[PBXPListUnarchiver decodeRootObject] (in DevToolsCore)
 20  0x00000001044e79e0 +[PBXProject projectWithFile:errorHandler:readOnly:] (in DevToolsCore)
 21  0x00000001047146ad -[Xcode3Project initWithFilePath:extension:workspace:options:error:] (in DevToolsCore)
 22  0x000000010317c71d __82+[IDEContainer _retainedContainerAtFilePath:fileDataType:workspace:options:error:]_block_invoke_2 (in IDEFoundation)
 23  0x00007fff91860c13 _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)
 24  0x00007fff91861e5e _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke (in libdispatch.dylib)
 25  0x0000000102a609cd DVTDispatchBarrierSync (in DVTFoundation)
 26  0x000000010285beb4 -[DVTDispatchLock performLockedBlock:] (in DVTFoundation)
 27  0x000000010317c129 __82+[IDEContainer _retainedContainerAtFilePath:fileDataType:workspace:options:error:]_block_invoke (in IDEFoundation)
 28  0x0000000102994ace __58-[DVTModelObjectGraph performBlockCoalescingModelChanges:]_block_invoke (in DVTFoundation)
 29  0x0000000102a1933a -[DVTModelGraphTransactionScope performTransaction:] (in DVTFoundation)
 30  0x00000001029949d9 -[DVTModelObjectGraph performBlockCoalescingModelChanges:] (in DVTFoundation)
 31  0x000000010317beb2 +[IDEContainer _retainedContainerAtFilePath:fileDataType:workspace:options:error:] (in IDEFoundation)
 32  0x0000000102e6b8f5 +[IDEContainer retainedContainerAtFilePath:fileDataType:workspace:error:] (in IDEFoundation)
 33  0x00000001031419dc -[IDEFileReference _recalculateReferencedContainer] (in IDEFoundation)
 34  0x0000000102e7e27b -[IDEFileReference referencedContainer] (in IDEFoundation)
 35  0x000000010317a9da __62-[IDEContainer _scheduleResolvePendingFileReferencesOperation]_block_invoke (in IDEFoundation)
 36  0x00000001029a00c8 -[_DVTAsynchronousRequest _invokeBlock:] (in DVTFoundation)
 37  0x00007fff90aa941b __NSFireDelayedPerform (in Foundation)
 38  0x00007fff8feb52e4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ (in CoreFoundation)
 39  0x00007fff8feb4f73 __CFRunLoopDoTimer (in CoreFoundation)
 40  0x00007fff8ff2853d __CFRunLoopDoTimers (in CoreFoundation)
 41  0x00007fff8fe70608 __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation)
 42  0x00007fff8fe6fbd8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation)
 43  0x0000000102996f0b +[DVTKVOConditionValidator waitForCondition:sourceObject:keyPathAffectingConditionBlock:timeout:] (in DVTFoundation)
 44  0x000000010358c7e3 -[Xcode3CommandLineBuildTool _resolveInputOptionsWithTimingSection:] (in Xcode3Core)
 45  0x000000010359c685 -[Xcode3CommandLineBuildTool run] (in Xcode3Core)
 46  0x00000001028509be (in xcodebuild)
 47  0x00007fff8b5b45c9 start (in libdyld.dylib)
 48  0x0000000000000004
```

I have latest Xcode. Appreciate any help, thanks

Comment: Hi. Check the schemes in the your app (Product->Scheme->Manage Schemes), they must be have shared (checkbox "shared").
If not, need to make shared and then commit changes to the repo.

Comment: @Mozilla, already checked, they are shared :/

Comment: Check the next - do checkout your project from the version control repo in the new folder, then open and check the schemes again. It's looks like your shared schemes not under git (svn). And can you give more informations about your project structure (maybe screenshot from the xcode - targets, workspace)? + Informations about the build steps from the Jenkins.

Comment: @Mozilla - schemes are shared and for sure they are under control, because I used some cloud - solution, where I've checked my repo and it required schemes to be shared, so it is for sure.

In my jenkins I basically check out project from git in previous step, then I'm pulling some submodules using 'execute shell' and run pod install manually. After that, I run job, which uses xcode build plugin. As I said, I'v tried to run same comand (xcodebuild -list ...) in the checked out folder from command line and it's fine there. What details exactly from target/workspace you may find useful?

Comment: small update, same problem occurs with any other project I'm trying to build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

found the solution, what helped me wast to set SDK in Xcode plugin to value returned by xcodebuild -sdk, which was iphoneos8.4.

Comment: How'd you dynamically set it to be set to value returned by `xcodebuild -sdk`?

Comment: I was getting this issue in azure devops pipeline and I simply added the argument `-sdk iphoneos` and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

it worked for me after I restarted Jenkins. The problem was that I had just installed xcode plugin and didn't restart the server afterwards.